# error: expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘=’ token in struct

Tags: c, struct, malloc, token

I'm getting the error when compiling with gcc -Wall -std=c99:

`pokerhand.c:20:17: error: expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘=’ token

Card *cards = malloc(sizeof(Card)*5);`

here is my code where the error is happening

```
typedef struct card 
{
    char suit;
    char *face;
} Card;

typedef struct hand 
{
    Card *cards = malloc(sizeof(Card)*5);
    char *result;
} Hand;
```

all I have before these structs is header includes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
```

Comment: A type definition is not executable code. It cannot hold initializations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't write code inside a struct declaration. That is wrong.

I bet this would solve the error

```
typedef struct hand 
{
    Card *cards;
    char *result;
} Hand;
```

And later you can allocate to it when you have proper variable declared with that type.

Also this would work

```
typedef struct hand 
{
    Card cards[5];
    char *result;
} Hand;
```

If you think that each `hand` would contain `5` card every single time then yes you can add it like this.

In the first case you need to allocate the `card`s and then free it when you are done working with it.

Comment: Oh jeez, thank you for the quick response. Still getting used to structs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't "do things" with the `struct` members when you define the `struct`.

So `Card *cards = malloc(sizeof(Card)*5);` makes no sense, and the compiler issues a diagnostic.

One solution is to build an `init_card` function, that takes a `struct card*` as an input parameter; and you perform your initialisation there. If you also build a corresponding `free_card` function you'll end up with something that scales up remarkably well.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I'm still getting used to structs.